How to send logs from NextJS to Azure Application Insights using OpenTelemetry and Winston?
I am using winston to log throughout my NextJS application. I want these logs to be collected in Azure Application Insights. Microsoft advises to do so using OpenTelemetry. My setup is as follows:
instrumentation.ts:
import { env } from "~/env";
import { logs } from "@opentelemetry/api-logs";
import { LoggerProvider, SimpleLogRecordProcessor, ConsoleLogRecordExporter } from "@opentelemetry/sdk-logs";
import { BatchSpanProcessor, NodeTracerProvider } from "@opentelemetry/sdk-trace-node";
import { Resource } from "@opentelemetry/resources";
import { registerOTel } from "@vercel/otel";
import { WinstonInstrumentation } from "@opentelemetry/instrumentation-winston";
import { ATTR_SERVICE_NAME } from "@opentelemetry/semantic-conventions";
import { registerInstrumentations } from "@opentelemetry/instrumentation";

export async function register() {
    if (
        process.env.NEXT_RUNTIME == "nodejs" &&
        env.APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING != null
    ) {
        console.log("Registering Application Insights");
        const { AzureMonitorTraceExporter, AzureMonitorLogExporter } =
            await import("@azure/monitor-opentelemetry-exporter");

        const tracerProvider = new NodeTracerProvider({
            resource: new Resource({
                [ATTR_SERVICE_NAME]: env.APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_SERVICE_NAME,
            }),
        });
        tracerProvider.register();
        const traceExporter = new AzureMonitorTraceExporter({
            connectionString: env.APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING,
        });
        tracerProvider.addSpanProcessor(
            new BatchSpanProcessor(traceExporter, {
                maxQueueSize: 10,
                scheduledDelayMillis: 5000,
            }),
        );
        const logExporter = new AzureMonitorLogExporter({
            connectionString: env.APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING,
        });
        // Set up OpenTelemetry logging provider
        const loggerProvider = new LoggerProvider();

        // Add a log processor that will export the logs
        loggerProvider.addLogRecordProcessor(
            new SimpleLogRecordProcessor(logExporter),
        );
        // Add a processor to export log record
        loggerProvider.addLogRecordProcessor(
            new SimpleLogRecordProcessor(new ConsoleLogRecordExporter()),
        );
        logs.setGlobalLoggerProvider(loggerProvider);

        const instrumentation = new WinstonInstrumentation({
            disableLogSending: false,
            enabled: true,
            disableLogCorrelation: false,
        });
        registerOTel({
            serviceName: env.APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_SERVICE_NAME,
            traceExporter,
            instrumentations: [instrumentation],
        });
        registerInstrumentations({
            instrumentations: [instrumentation],
        });
    } else {

    }
}

My winston setup is as follows:
import { env } from "~/env";
import winston, { type Logger } from "winston";
import { OpenTelemetryTransportV3 } from "@opentelemetry/winston-transport";

// Create a logger with custom format
const logger: Logger = winston.createLogger({
    transports: [
        new winston.transports.Console({
            level: env.NODE_ENV == "test" ? "error" : "debug",
            format: winston.format.simple(),
        }),
        new OpenTelemetryTransportV3(),
    ],
});
export default logger;

The application does show that the instrumentation code is being executed, and I do get request time information in Application Insights, but the traces table in Application Insights remains empty. What am I doing wrong?

I found out what the correct configuration is for using NextJS with Winston and Azure Application Insights through OpenTelemetry. Here is my instrumentation.ts
import { WinstonInstrumentation } from "@opentelemetry/instrumentation-winston";
import { BatchLogRecordProcessor } from "@opentelemetry/sdk-logs";
import { env } from "~/env";
import { registerOTel } from "@vercel/otel";

// Prevent registering the SDK multiple times
let started = false;

export async function register() {
    if (
        !started &&
        process.env.NEXT_RUNTIME == "nodejs" &&
        env.APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING != null
    ) {
        started = true;
        console.log("Registering Azure Application Insights");

        // Importing the Azure Monitor cannot be done when in Edge environment
        const { AzureMonitorLogExporter, AzureMonitorTraceExporter } =
            await import("@azure/monitor-opentelemetry-exporter");

        // Configure Azure Exporters
        const params = {
            connectionString: env.APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING,
        };
        const traceExporter = new AzureMonitorTraceExporter(params);
        const logExporter = new AzureMonitorLogExporter(params);

        // Register the OpenTelemetry provider
        registerOTel({
            serviceName: env.APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_SERVICE_NAME,
            traceExporter,
            logRecordProcessor: new BatchLogRecordProcessor(logExporter, {
                maxExportBatchSize: 100,
            }),
            instrumentations: [
                new WinstonInstrumentation({
                    disableLogSending: false,
                    disableLogCorrelation: false,
                    enabled: true,
                }),
            ],
        });
    }
}

And logger.ts which is used to log by the rest of the code:
import { env } from "~/env";

// For if not being run through 'next start' or 'next dev' 
import { register } from "~/instrumentation";
await register();

import { OpenTelemetryTransportV3 } from "@opentelemetry/winston-transport";
import winston, { type Logger } from "winston";
import { context, trace } from "@opentelemetry/api";

// Create a logger with custom format
const logger: Logger = winston.createLogger({
    format: winston.format.combine(
        winston.format.timestamp({ format: "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss" }),
        winston.format.printf(({ level, message, timestamp }) => {
            // Retrieve the current span from OpenTelemetry context
            const span = trace.getSpan(context.active());
            const traceId = span ? span.spanContext().traceId : "unknown";
            return `${timestamp} [traceId=${traceId}] ${level}: ${message}`;
        }),
    ),
    transports: [
        new winston.transports.Console({
            level: env.NODE_ENV == "test" ? "error" : "debug",
            format: winston.format.simple(),
        }),
        new OpenTelemetryTransportV3({}),
    ],
});
export default logger;


To resolve your issue with Winston logs not appearing in Azure Application Insights, follow these steps:

Check Connection String: Ensure APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING is correctly set in your environment variables.
Configure Log Exporter: Make sure AzureMonitorLogExporter is properly set up and added to the LoggerProvider.
Persist User State: Verify that userType and token are stored and retrieved from local storage.



const logExporter = new AzureMonitorLogExporter({
    connectionString: env.APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING,
});
const loggerProvider = new LoggerProvider();
loggerProvider.addLogRecordProcessor(new SimpleLogRecordProcessor(logExporter));
logs.setGlobalLoggerProvider(loggerProvider);




Thank you for your answer. 1. This can not be the issue, as the request timing information does get uploaded to Application Insights. 2. You can see in my code how I configured the log exporter. Did I do anything wrong? 3. What do you mean with this? 4. Why have you copied a piece of my code?
